# How does computing table stats in hive or impala speed up queries in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

For increasing performance (e.g. for joins) it is recommended to compute table statics first.

In Hive I can do::

```
analyze table <table name> compute statistics;
```

In Impala:

```
compute stats <table name>;
```

Does my spark application (reading from hive-tables) also benefit from pre-computed statistics? If yes, which one do I need to run? Are they both saving the stats in the hive metastore? I'm using spark 1.6.1 on Cloudera 5.5.4

Note:
In the Docs of spark 1.6.1 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html) for the parameter `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` I found a hint:

> Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore
>   tables where the command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS
>   noscan has been run.

Comment: Will analyze table in Hive and compute stats in impala store stats in same meta store or different locations? Because we only run compute stats in impala, but also use hive to run complex queries.

Answer (score 6):

This is the upcoming Spark 2.3.0 here (perhaps some of the features have already been released in 2.2.1 or ealier).

> Does my spark application (reading from hive-tables) also benefit from pre-computed statistics?

It could if Impala or Hive recorded the table statistics (e.g. table size or row count) in a Hive metastore in the table metadata that Spark can read from (and translate to its own Spark statistics for query planning).

You can easily check it out by using `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` SQL command in `spark-shell`.

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT

scala> sql("DESC EXTENDED t1 id").show
+--------------+----------+
|info_name     |info_value|
+--------------+----------+
|col_name      |id        |
|data_type     |int       |
|comment       |NULL      |
|min           |0         |
|max           |1         |
|num_nulls     |0         |
|distinct_count|2         |
|avg_col_len   |4         |
|max_col_len   |4         |
|histogram     |NULL      |
+--------------+----------+
```

`ANALYZE TABLE COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan` computes one statistic that Spark uses, i.e. the total size of a table (with no row count metric due to `noscan` option). If Impala and Hive recorded it to a "proper" location, Spark SQL would show it in `DESC EXTENDED`.

Use `DESC EXTENDED tableName` for table-level statistics and see if you find the ones that were generated by Impala or Hive. If they are in `DESC EXTENDED`'s output they will be used for optimizing joins (and with cost-based optimization turned on also for aggregations and filters).

---

Column statistics are stored (in a Spark-specific serialized format) in table properties and I really doubt that Impala or Hive could compute the stats and store them in the Spark SQL-compatible format.

Comment: Hi @laskowski, we would like to query data from Cassandra via Spark with Spark-Cassandra-Connector. It is interesting that all Cassandra table will be registered as ‘temp view’. May I know if also can analyze temp view? I tried but failed. Now sure if it is because of any misconfiguration or it is not supported. Many thanks for your hints.

Comment: _"May I know if also can analyze temp view? I tried but failed."_ Not possible. Temp views are temporary and so cannot leverage any permanent storage like a metastore. Moreover, I don't think you need that. All the `ANALYZE TABLE` are to give enough info to the planner and the connector should handle it itself with ease to give enough info.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using Hive on Spark (or) Spark-Sql with hive context. If that is the case, you should run analyze in hive.

Analyze table<...> typically needs to run after the table is created or if there are significant inserts/changes. You can do this at the end of your load step itself, if this is a MR or spark job.

At the time of analysis, if you are using hive on spark - please also use the configurations in the link below. You can set this at the session level for each query. I have used the parameters in this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started in production and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand compute stats on impala is the latest implementation and frees you from tuning hive settings.

**From official doc:**

> If you use the Hive-based methods of gathering statistics, see the
>   Hive wiki for information about the required configuration on the Hive
>   side. Cloudera recommends using the Impala COMPUTE STATS statement to
>   avoid potential configuration and scalability issues with the
>   statistics-gathering process.
>
> If you run the Hive statement ANALYZE TABLE COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR
>   COLUMNS, Impala can only use the resulting column statistics if the
>   table is unpartitioned. Impala cannot use Hive-generated column
>   statistics for a partitioned table.

Useful link:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_perf_stats.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this only answers the question for Impala, not if Spark can use the hereby calculated statistics.